# SSRS Dynamic Graphs

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, graph, business-intelligence

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a graph(s) at run time based on the dataset?

To clarify, I have a count of patients suffering from a health condition, split by week. I need to make a graph per condition with weeks on the X axis and patient count on the Y. Nice and easy so far.

The problem is that the number of conditions displayed in the dataset will be different depending on the values entered for the start and end dates for the reporting date range.

With this in mind can I create a single graph then tell it to replicate once for each condition returned and only look at the data for that specific condition?

The graphs can't appear in rows as they must aggregate data from multiple rows (where the condition is the same) and plot the various count values over week numbers (the dataset returns a count, a week number and a condition with a group by on the week number and condition)

As an added challenge none of this can be hard coded as the single report has to work across multiple sites.

Thanks

P

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible by first dropping a "Matrix" control into the report surface.  With the Matrix control, you're able to display groups of data.  In this case, your group will be the condition returned in your DataSet.  Each group will have an embedded chart which will display data the same way, but only the data within the grouping you choose.

Step 1:  Add a Matrix control to your report surface.  Create a Row Group based on Condition (In my example, Year)

[image]

Step 2:  Right Click the empty column on the right side of the Matrix control, and choose the option for Insert Column > Outside Group - Right.  Then Delete the middle column.

[image]

Step 3:  Right click the Right columns "Data" cell (which should be outside the grouping) and choose Insert > Chart.  Select the desired chart type.

[image]

Step 4:  Resize the column and row to view the chart in more detail.  Edit the Chart Data to aggregate what you're wanting to show as the line, and pick your category groups.

[image]

Step 5:  Test, and revist whichever step above needs adjusting.

[image]

Comment: This is one of those replies that makes you see an entirely new way of doing what you do each day. I'm sure I'll use this for years to come. Thanks you!

Comment: Lol, this is exactly what I do every day (when I'm not at SO helping people - shh don't tell my boss!)

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give this a thorough test tomorrow and mark as answered.

Comment: I have had more time to take in your solution now and unfortunately I don't think its going to work for me.
The graphs can't appear in rows as they must aggregate data from multiple rows (where the condition is the same) and plot the various count values over week numbers (the dataset returns a count, a week number and a condition with a group by on the week number and condition).
It's a very elegant answer and I'm sure I'll use it in the future but it wont work for me here.
Thanks again
P

Comment: That would have been good information to have in your question...  If you could give an edit to the question with better detail, maybe I can alter my answer to get you past the finish line.

Comment: My apologies, I had got ahead of myself and was trying to figure out issues before the rpt was fleshed out. Ill edit now

Comment: I have found a solution - however the chart become stretched to fit the area, and makes the whole table and graphic difficult to read.

Basically, you do the exact same steps as I have outlined above with a Tablix, not a Matrix and you add "Child Groups" for each of the 'rows' you want to combine in the Chart row.